# How do I specify the collection for Serilog.Sinks.MongDB sink

Tags: mongodb, serilog

The documentation on github uses the following connection string:

```
.WriteTo.MongoDB("mongo://mymongodb/log")
```

It says that for this example to work you need to add a collection named log to your server.  However, this connection string will connect you to the log database on your server and not specify any collection.  I can't find any information about specifying a collection in a connection string (which makes sense), so how do I tell the MongoDB sink which collection to write to?

I added SelfLog.Out = Console.Out to the application, but I don't see anything in the Output window that will assist me.

Later: I added a collection named "log" to my database and Serilog is writing to that collection.  So it appears that "log" is baked into the driver.  I want two different logs for this particular database.  So my question remains.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the source code and add a collection parameter to the signature of the MongoDB LoggerConfiguration class constructor.  The changed code is marked with **.

```
public static LoggerConfiguration MongoDB(
    this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
    string databaseUrl,
    **string collectionName = null,**
    LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum,
    int batchPostingLimit = MongoDBSink.DefaultBatchPostingLimit,
    TimeSpan? period = null,
    IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if (loggerConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("loggerConfiguration");
    if (databaseUrl == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("databaseUrl");

    var defaultedPeriod = period ?? MongoDBSink.DefaultPeriod;
    return loggerConfiguration.Sink(
        new MongoDBSink(
            databaseUrl,
            batchPostingLimit,
            defaultedPeriod,
            formatProvider,
            **collectionName ??** MongoDBSink.DefaultCollectionName,
            new CreateCollectionOptions()),
        restrictedToMinimumLevel);
}
```